# ZF2 Framework 3rd party modules implementation and limitation

Tags: php, module, zend-framework2

We're in the process of building an application entirely based on ZF2. The application is split into 3 main divisions namely a Core, API and Front End section / division.

At some point, we want to open the system up for people to develop 3rd party modules which will go on offer for inclusion in the different profiles customers have. These 3rd party modules would either extend functionality or be able to enhance existing processes by hooking into events fired from the Core Level.

These 3rd party modules could use the API, however, the current API is outward focused and does not lend itself to enhancing and extending the system from this perspective.

So, the alternative would be to allow access to the Core directly, which we feel might not be desirable as we must have a means to control access to these vital components and underlying data.

I am considering building a separate API aimed at trying to manage access from a module level within the Application life cycle, however, I am not entirely sure how something like this would look like.

The folder structure would look something like the following:

-config

-data

-AppCore

--Core

--CoreForms

--CoreContacts

-AppAPI

--APIForms

--APIContacts

-APPFront      (This fodler will be into a seperate instance of ZF2 installation and communicate via the APPApi)

--FrontForms

--FrontContacts

-3rdPartyModules

-public

-vendor

Developed modules would reside within the 3rdPartyModules folder within the entire structure.

The question is, how would one go about limiting access to Core resources, for instance, any 3rd party modules must not be able to consume the standard database adapter. In this case, db_adapter (Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter).

These modules will have a separate database setup where data should be stored specific to these modules, so something like db_adapter_3rdparty would be made available instead.

I have considered using interfaces to be implemented within these 3rd party modules and then have a check performed by any of the core module classes and functions, however, this would be cumbersome and inefficient.

Currently, the API functionality is only accessible via REST, so that would not be option for hooking into the system as keys would become involved and be an admin nightmare.

So the question is then, allowing modules to be installed within the overall application, would you be able to limit access to application resources, if so, what would be the most efficient way of implementing such control and whether it is a good idea to allow this to take place?

I've done quite a bit searching and could not find anything close along the lines of what is required, apart from actually installing modules, configuring them etc.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're allowing PHP code to be installed in the application I don't see how you could restrict what it could access. E.g. even if you were able to somehow stop them from using the DB adapter, there's nothing stopping them reading in your config and creating another instance of it.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Tim. Would you know of best practices in setting up a external/3rd party module capability for a system or some other ideas on this matter?